# Python: 2-D variable not retaining value after 'insert' operation

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
temp={}
L=[2,4,6]
temp[0]=[1,2,3]  #ignore
temp[1]=[4,5,6]  #ignore
L.insert(1,3)    
temp[2]=L
print(temp[2])   #before insert
L.insert(2,3)
temp[3]=L
print(temp[3])
print(temp[2])   #after insert
```

the temp[2] variable doesn't retain it's value after the second insert operation. Rather, it takes after the new value of L, which should, in no way otherwise, be affected by this operation, in my opinion.

You can see the difference in values of temp[2] in the print statements one before, and one after the insert.

If anyone could, please explain what exactly is happening in the back-end.. I'm totally new to python (2 day old learner), so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one list in your code, whether you store it or modify it, it's still the same list:

```
temp = {}  # create a dictionary "temp"
L = [2, 4, 6]  # create a list "L"
L.insert(1, 3) # insert elements into list that "L" names
temp[2] = L  # add what "L" names into the dictionary (not a copy)
print(temp[2])  # print that same dictionary value
L.insert(2, 3)  # modify the list that "L" names
temp[3] = L  # insert that same list into the dictionary under a new key (not a copy)
print(temp[3])  # print that same dictionary value
print(temp[2])  # print the previous dictionary value
```

If you want to store its *current state*, you need to copy it:

```
...
temp[2] = list(L)  # add a copy of what "L" names into the dictionary
print(temp[2])  # print that same dictionary value
L.insert(2, 3)  # modify the original list that "L" names
temp[3] = list(L)  # insert that a copy of the modified list into the dictionary under a new key
print(temp[3])  # print that same dictionary value
print(temp[2])  # print the previous dictionary value
```

The program did the correct thing -- it's your expectations that need a slight adjustment.